# Is there any way to reject an edit after the fact?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I ran across a clearly invalid, but approved [edit-as-comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9102612/revisions) by an anonymous user. I can roll it back, obviously; and, given the edit was anonymous, it's not like I could give the original editor-commenter useful rejection feedback in any case. But it feels like there ought to be something stronger than a rollback, possibly dinging the OP for [approving the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5981190).

Not that I really want to pile on the OP, who at least had the grace to let criticism of his answer stand. But if it had been a third-party review approval, it seems like that might deserve a rap on the knuckles.

[image]

Comment: If 3 reviewers had approved it you could *potentially* flag for bad reviews, not really anything to be done about the OP approving it though; after all they really could appropriately edit that content into their own answer.

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing why people are downvoting, btw.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, the first being to roll it back then add the update as a comment.

However, I'd probably just edit the answer to reword it in such a way that the comment becomes a limitation of the answer, something like 'Note that this solution assumes you don't need to look in subdirectories. If that's needed, you'll have to find another way.'.

I see no issue with answers stating their assumptions and limitations.